# Spring and Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, ioc-container, autowired

I need to start a variable number of threads which in turn each start a varying number of threads (i.e. i threads where the Ith thread needs to start Ki threads) in a spring application.
assuming each of the "I threads" contains an inner class which is autowired how will I generate those instances?
So I have an `A bean` which needs to somehow generate `I` instances of a bean which needs to be spring managed to satisfy its dependencies.

I've written a short sample code of what I think is the base for my solution and I've marked the code I'm not sure how to write by ???:

```
@Component
public class MasterOrchestrator {    
 public void do(List<DataObjWrapper> list){
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(list.size());
    for (DataObjWrapper dataObjWrapper : list){
        es.submit(???);
    }
 }    
}
@Component
public class ThreadWorkerI implements Runnable{    
    private int numThreadsForMessageType;
    private int numRunsForMessageType;
    private DataObj dataObj;
        public ThreadWorkerI(int numThreadsForMessageType, int numRunsForMessageType, DataObj dataObj){
        this.numThreadsForMessageType = numThreadsForMessageType;
        this.numRunsForMessageType = numRunsForMessageType;
        this.dataObj = dataObj;
    }
        @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;   
    public void run(){  
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreadsForMessageType);
        for (int i=0;i<numRunsForMessageType;i++){
            es.submit(new ActualWorker(i));
        }       
    }

    private class ActualWorker implements Runnable{
        private int numRun;
        private ActualWorker(int numRun){
            this.numRun = numRun;
        }
        public void run(){
            //send message using the jmsTemplate the dataObj and numRun
        }
    }
}
```

`DatObjWrapper` contains amongst other members the `numThreadsForMessageType`, `numRunsForMessageType` and `dataObj`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [@Configurable](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable) annotation to let Spring inject dependencies into your workers - even the one's that are not managed explicitly by the Spring container.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. From the looks of the link and some quick googling it seems that @Configurable can solve the issue I'm just not sure if it's the "spring way" of solving it. I'll wait a bit to see if someone offers a way which allows me to stay in the container and still answer my needs. If not I'll accept your answer (I've upvoted you already).

Comment: Also, just to verify, since I'm new to the weaving business- If I'm using LTW then I only pay a "serious" price the first instantiation of an object of a class right? Afterwards it's like a regular spring bean (which of course has some overhead)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting your own threads it is better to use thread pool or Spring's [task executor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-executor) abstraction. Then your tasks can be Spring beans or manually instantiated.

Comment: I went over the link you give here (before) and I wasn't sure how this can help me. Notice that in the example they're instantiating themselves the `MessagePrinterTask` instances which means there not spring managed beans. If the "I threads" were somehow spring managed beans then they could have autowired what I need and they would instantiate an inner class which has access to their autowired resource. The problem is with the first link. I can just do context.getBean I times but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 0):

How about passing a reference to the MasterOrchestrator or the ThreadWorker into the Runnable's constructor?  Then you can put all the configuration into the @Component class.

For example:

```
 private class ActualWorker implements Runnable{
      private int numRun;
      private ActualWorker(ThreadWorkerI owner, int numRun){
          this.numRun = numRun;
      }
      public void run(){
          //send message using owner.jmsTemplate, owner.dataObj and numRun
      }
  }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this feels like a workaround to me. I also think Biju's solution is a workaround but it's a bit more elegant since the ActualWorker is managed in a way. I'm still looking for the "spring way" of doing this. If I'll find it I'll update here.